# Divs out of place in IE7 & 8

Tags: internet-explorer, html, css-float, joomla-template

I have a problem with 3 divs in this project, menu, banner and footer are out of place in IE but in firefox, safari and google chrome they appear in a right place.

I m new in joomla and i made the template from the scratch, i need help to figured out this issues, i try search the forum and check similar problems but i d'ont find a solution.

The link:

http://staging.socinterangola.com

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can anyone hel p me with this problems, i apreciate a lot thank you

Answer (score 0):

The machine I'm currently on doesn't have IE so I'll have to guess a little - sorry.

The Banner div is floated left and has a left margin. This is a classic issue with IE - if you float in a direction and have a margin on that side the margin gets doubled. Solution: put a margin right of the same value on the item you are floating against.  Alternatively make the banner div wider by putting padding inside on the left instead of a margin on outside the left.

MenuNav has the same issue - left margin and floated left. Again, in IE (6,7 and 8 I think) margins get doubled when they are on the same side you float to.

On the footer the only thing I see that is suspicious is a negative margin on the top. This is ignored by some browsers and not others - so is a probable cause of your issue.

Hope that helps - but does involve a little guesswork as I say.